# Is there a way to mute students with Google Classroom API?

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-classroom

[way to mute student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np3vN.png)

I need not only to exclude with API, but also mute.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no API to perform mutes.